# SharePoint REST API: case sensitivity on filter

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to filter (search) results using the SP REST API.

Currently, a search for 'Data protection' will not return results as SP is looking for a perfect match of 'Data Protection'.

Does SP REST API have a case-sensitivity option?